# Android calendar BroadcastReceiver host : com.android.calendar vs com.google.android.calendar

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentprovider, android-broadcast

After looking around a bit, I've noticed there are 2 possible hosts for the Android calendar.
The first is `com.android.calendar` and the other is `com.google.android.calendar`.
I'm pretty sure it reflects the new standalone calendar Google released last year, but other than that I'm clueless.
What is the difference? When should I use the first and when the other?

Comment: AFAIK, Android doesn't have a notion of host. What do you mean by _there are 2 possible hosts_?

Answer (score 2):

- `com.android.calendar` is the AOSP calendar.
- `com.google.android.calendar` is Google calendar.

If you want to interact with the phone calendar, you are interested by the the content provider from former.